# Password protecting a program without third party software with an encrypted password on windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file, passwords

Been testing it for a few days now and my original idea was to use a .bat file to ask for an input, the problem is that the password is not encrypted and therefore I can't use it as it is now.

Found this .bat script that does what I want but is not encrypted:

```
@Echo off
cls
:Password
Set input=
set /p input= Password (input then press enter) :
if %input%==star goto YES
if not %input%==star goto NO

:YES

Start MSpaint.exe
Exit

:NO

Echo INCORRECT PASSWORD
goto Password
```

If there is a command or something I can add so the password will not be seen while it's being typed should work out as well.

Comment: What are you actually trying to secure by this? As a batch file needs to be readable to the user he will be able to read it either way. If you want to make it a bit harder you could use a hash and an additional tool that lets you calculate hashes and compare the hashes (something which is usually done).

Comment: Just use EFS, encrypt the files in question, skip the useless batch files that doesn’t prevent anything from being start from anyone

Comment: Any script you right will NOT prevent anyone from manually running the program themselves.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a utility such as
[RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html)
with which you may call a program, requiring a password.
The password and all other details are kept by RunAsSpc in an encrypted database.
It can do `runas` plus password plus encryption (although the user can be you yourself).

RunAsSpc is free for private use.
For more details about using it see the article
[Pass the password to Runas with RunAsSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/guidance.html).

For simpler protection,
you could use a [Md5 generator](https://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/)
to generate a hash of the password.
The batch file will then ask for a password but will compare its MD5 hash
rather than the password itself.

For an even simpler protection against non-sophisticated users,
you might sprinkle references to undefined environmental variables
around your batch file. Such variables come up as empty when evaluated,
but they will dissuade reading the batch file.

Using this idea, the following script :

```
@echo off
echo "Hello, world!"
```

may look like this :

```
@%n%e%x%c%s%h%z%o%f% o%d%f%d%f
e%n%c%o%h%n%o %n%H%p%e%n%l%o%l%o%o%o%,%o% w%c%o%n%r%p%l%k%d%e%!%s%
```

Comment: sounds good but we will be using the script commercially so i will have to run it by the higher ups. But thanks for the tip :)